# Search for substring, return another substring

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I need to search for and display a part of a string field.  The string value from record to record may be different.  For example:

---

Record #1

String Value:

```
IA_UnsafesclchOffense0IA_ReceivedEdServDuringExp0IA_SeriousBodilyInjuryN
```

---

Record #2

String Value:

```
 IA_ReasonForRemovalTIA_Beh_Inc_Num1392137419IA_RemovalTypeNIA_UnsafesclchOffense0IA_ReceivedEdServDuringExp0IA_SeriousBodilyInjuryN
```

---

Record #3

String Value:

```
IA_UnsafesclchOffense0IA_RemovalTypeSIA_ReasonForRemovalPIA_ReceivedEdServDuringExp0IA_Beh_Inc_Num1396032888IA_SeriousBodilyInjuryN
```

---

In each case, I need to search for `IA_Beh_Inc_Num`.  Assuming it's found, and IF it's followed by numeric data, I want to RETURN the numeric portion of that data.  The numeric data, when present, will always be 10 characters.
In other words, record #1 should return no value, record #2 should return 1392137419 and record #3 should return 1396032888

Is there a way to do this within a select statement without having to write a full function with PL/SQL?

Comment: Can you show us your current SQL Statement?

Comment: can you for sure make the assumption that the number will be ten digits long? Example. never 9 if starting with a zero, etc

Comment: @arserbin Yes, it will always be 10 digits long.  I'm capturing a unix timestamp for that value.

Comment: @Leptonator Honestly, I didn't even know where to begin...  so I don't have a current select statement.  :(

Comment: @Brian Brock Consider selecting a correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN instr(value, 'IA_Beh_Inc_Num') > 0
     THEN substr(substr(value, instr(value, 'IA_Beh_Inc_Num'), 25),15,10)
     ELSE 'not found'
END AS result
FROM example
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9c0ed/9/0).

Answer (score 2):

This should be easy with a Regular Expression: find a search string and check if it's followed by 10 digits:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '(?<=IA_Beh_Inc_Num)([0-9]{10})')
```

but Oracle doesn't seem to support RegEx *lookahead*, so it's bit more complicated:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(IA_Beh_Inc_Num)([0-9]{10})',1,1,'i',2)
```

Remarks: the search is case-insensitive and if there are less than 10 digits NULL will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Angelo's answer is correct for Oracle, as the question asked.
For those from SQL Server coming across this, the below would work:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('IA_Beh_Inc_Num', StringColumn) = 0
            THEN NULL
        ELSE SUBSTRING(StringColumn, CHARINDEX('IA_Beh_Inc_Num', StringColumn) + LEN('IA_Beh_Inc_Num'), 10)
        END AS unix_time
    ,*
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

Modified query to select all rows. The query prints "NOT A TIMESTAMP" if `IA_Beh_Inc_Num` does not exist within the string or if it is not followed by 10 numbers.

```
SELECT
  DECODE
    (
    REGEXP_INSTR (value, 'IA_Beh_Inc_Num[0-9]{10}'), 
    0, 
    'NOT A TIMESTAMP', 
    SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, 'IA_Beh_Inc_Num')+14, 10)
    ) timestamp
FROM example;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc5fb/24)

Comment: Thank you Joseph B.  Unfortunately does not work for me as it would exclude records that do not contain 'IA_Beh_Inc_Num'.

Comment: @BrianBrock I see. I am changing the query to remove the condition. Also, simplifying. Also, changing the query to print the timestamp, only if numeric characters are present.

Comment: @BrianBrock Updated the query. This query will also check if IA_Beh_Inc_Num is followed by 10 numbers.